# I am not understanding MySQL Joins at all. I'm stuck

Tags: mysql, join

So I'm trying to learn some MySQL and I have gotten to a point on Joins. It is doing my head in.

I have a few exercises I am trying to work through and getting no where.

The current exercise calls for this:

Use the pre-1994 SQL syntax (i.e. do not use the INNER JOIN syntax) to display the order date, order number and the shipper company name for orders shipped to
Portugal. Sort the output in ascending order of order date.

I currently have typed this:

```
SELECT OrderDate, OrderID, ShipperID FROM Shippers Orders
WHERE shippers.shipperID = orders.shipperID AND orders.shipcountry = 'Portugal';
```

But I am getting this error message:
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'OrderDate' in 'field list'

What am I doing wrong? Also, what can I provide to help you guys to help me?

OrderDate DOES exist, as you can see here from my screenshot here of 'Select * from Orders'
[image]

So I imagine that is similar but with a different join process.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Column and table names are can be case sensitive on some systems so try and match them up. Maybe you're getting errors because of that?

Comment: This is a bonkers assignment. Anyway, you're missing a comma, which would cause one table name to become an alias of the other

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry, I added the comma. I now however get this error: Error Code: 1052. Column 'ShipperID' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Remove the ambiguity from the select clause - just as you did in the WHERE clause

Comment: Sorry to be naive but what does that mean exactly?

Comment: I think @Strawberry meant to add, "...by appending the range variable name and a dot to the column reference e.g. change `SELECT OrderDate, ...` to `SELECT Orders.OrderDate, ...`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use table name with column names to identify that which column belongs to which table.

```
SELECT orders.OrderDate, orders.OrderID,shippers.ShipperID FROM Shippers, Orders
WHERE shippers.shipperID = orders.shipperID AND orders.shipcountry = 'Portugal';
```

Or you can you aliasing that will be easy to write the query.

```
SELECT b.OrderDate, b.OrderID, a.ShipperID FROM Shippers a, Orders b
    WHERE a.shipperID = b.shipperID AND b.shipcountry = 'Portugal';
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: "You have to use table name with column names" - should read more like: "You have to use range variable references with column references"; I guess you are also making the point that when you don't explicitly specify a range variable name then the range variable reference defaults to the table's name.

Comment: "you can you aliasing" - I guess you are making the point you can specify a a range variable name to save typing the (presumably longer) default reference, being the table's name.

Comment: "to identify that which column belongs to which table" - actually, the range variable references a *row*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
 SELECT o.OrderDate, o.OrderID, s.ShipperID FROM Shippers s, Orders o
 WHERE s.shipperID = o.shipperID AND o.shipcountry = 'Portugal';
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use the pre-1994 SQL syntax

Sounds like the training course is taking you the long way around (though the date is wrong; probably should be 1989)!

The lesson here is that doing a relational product operation between two tables (a.k.a. `CROSS JOIN` to use the 1992 term, which remains outside core Standard SQL) forces you to use SQL's dot qualified references in the form `<range variable reference>.<column reference>` in order to disambiguate what would otherwise be duplicated column references (e.g. in your case where `shipperID` appears in both tables).

I guess the ultimate destination is `NATURAL JOIN`, where the need for range variables is dispensed with entirely!